SIFT Keypoint Detection for Image in C++
This is a follow-up question for difference_of_gaussian Template Function Implementation for Image in C++, conv2 Template Function Implementation for Image in C++ and imgaussfilt Template Function Implementation for Image in C++. I am trying to perform SIFT (Scale Invariant Feature Transform) keypoint detection (with get_potential_keypoint template function). There are several steps included:

Build several difference-of-Gaussian (DoG) images in several octaves (with generate_octave template function).

Find local maxima and minima pixels as keypoints in difference-of-Gaussian (DoG) images (with is_it_extremum template function and find_local_extrema template function).

Refine these keypoints' location using Taylor expansion (with keypoint_refinement template function).

Filter keypoints based on contrast and edge response (with keypoint_filtering template function).

Plot keypoints on the image (with draw_point, draw_points template functions).


The output example image (The white points are the detected keypoints):

The experimental implementation

is_it_extremum template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace SIFT_impl {
        /*  is_it_extremum template function implementation
            input1, input2 and input3 are 3 * 3 images. If the center pixel (at location (1,1) ) of input2 is the largest / smallest one, 
            return true; otherwise, return false.
            Test: https://godbolt.org/z/Kb34EW5Yj
        */
        template<typename ElementT>
        constexpr static bool is_it_extremum(Image<ElementT> input1, Image<ElementT> input2, Image<ElementT> input3, double threshold = 0.03)
        {
            if (input1.getDimensionality() != 2)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
            }
            if (input2.getDimensionality() != 2)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
            }
            if (input3.getDimensionality() != 2)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
            }
            if (input1.getWidth() != 3 || input1.getHeight() != 3)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Size error!");
            }
            if (input2.getWidth() != 3 || input2.getHeight() != 3)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Size error!");
            }
            if (input3.getWidth() != 3 || input3.getHeight() != 3)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Size error!");
            }
            auto center_pixel = input2.at(1, 1);
            auto input2_img_data = input2.getImageData();
            input2_img_data.erase(input2_img_data.begin() + 4);                         //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/875117/6667035
            if (std::abs(center_pixel) > threshold)
            {
                if (std::ranges::all_of(input1.getImageData(), [&](ElementT i) { return center_pixel > i; }) &&
                    std::ranges::all_of(input3.getImageData(), [&](ElementT i) { return center_pixel > i; }) &&
                    std::ranges::all_of(input2_img_data, [&](ElementT i) { return center_pixel > i; }))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if (std::ranges::all_of(input1.getImageData(), [&](ElementT i) { return center_pixel < i; }) &&
                    std::ranges::all_of(input3.getImageData(), [&](ElementT i) { return center_pixel < i; }) &&
                    std::ranges::all_of(input2_img_data, [&](ElementT i) { return center_pixel < i; }))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}


keypoint_refinement template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace SIFT_impl {
        //  keypoint_refinement template function implementation
        //  refine the given keypoint's location using Taylor expansion
        template<typename ElementT = double>
        constexpr static auto keypoint_refinement(
            Image<ElementT>& input,
            std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t> point
            )
        {
            //  Calculate the gradient at the keypoint (x, y)
            ElementT first_derivative_x = (input.at(2, 1) - input.at(0, 1)) / 2.0;
            ElementT first_derivative_y = (input.at(1, 2) - input.at(1, 0)) / 2.0;
            ElementT second_derivative_x = (input.at(2, 1) + input.at(0, 1) - 2.0 * input.at(1, 1));
            ElementT second_derivative_y = (input.at(1, 2) + input.at(1, 0) - 2.0 * input.at(1, 1));
            ElementT second_derivative_xy = (input.at(2, 2) - input.at(2, 0) - input.at(0, 2) + input.at(0, 0)) / 4.0;
            ElementT A = -second_derivative_x / (second_derivative_x * second_derivative_y - second_derivative_xy * second_derivative_xy);
            ElementT B = second_derivative_xy / (second_derivative_x * second_derivative_y - second_derivative_xy * second_derivative_xy);
            ElementT C = B;
            ElementT D = -second_derivative_y / (second_derivative_x * second_derivative_y - second_derivative_xy * second_derivative_xy);
            ElementT offset_x = A * first_derivative_x + B * first_derivative_y;
            ElementT offset_y = C * first_derivative_x + D * first_derivative_y;
            return std::make_tuple(
                static_cast<ElementT>(std::get<0>(point)) + offset_x,
                static_cast<ElementT>(std::get<1>(point)) + offset_y);
        }
    }
}


keypoint_filtering template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace SIFT_impl {
        //  keypoint_filtering template function implementation
        template<typename ElementT = double>
        constexpr static bool keypoint_filtering(
            Image<ElementT>& input,
            ElementT contrast_check_threshold = 8,
            ElementT edge_response_threshold = 12.1)
        {
            //  Calculate Hessian matrix at the keypoint (x, y)
            ElementT second_derivative_x = (input.at(2, 1) + input.at(0, 1) - 2.0 * input.at(1, 1));                    //  D_{xx}
            ElementT second_derivative_y = (input.at(1, 2) + input.at(1, 0) - 2.0 * input.at(1, 1));                    //  D_{yy}
            ElementT second_derivative_xy = (input.at(2, 2) - input.at(2, 0) - input.at(0, 2) + input.at(0, 0)) / 4.0;  //  D_{xy}
            ElementT trace_Hessian_matrix = second_derivative_x + second_derivative_y;
            ElementT determinant_Hessian_matrix = second_derivative_x * second_derivative_y - second_derivative_xy * second_derivative_xy;
            ElementT principal_curvature_ratio = trace_Hessian_matrix * trace_Hessian_matrix / determinant_Hessian_matrix;
            if (input.at(1, 1) <= contrast_check_threshold || principal_curvature_ratio >= edge_response_threshold)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}


mapping_point template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace SIFT_impl {
        //  mapping_point function implementation
        constexpr static std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t> mapping_point(
            std::tuple<double, double> input_location,
            std::size_t input_width,
            std::size_t input_height,
            std::size_t target_width,
            std::size_t target_height)
        {
            double width_percentage = static_cast<double>(std::get<0>(input_location)) / static_cast<double>(input_width);
            double height_percentage = static_cast<double>(std::get<1>(input_location)) / static_cast<double>(input_height);
            return std::make_tuple(
                static_cast<std::size_t>(width_percentage * static_cast<double>(target_width)),
                static_cast<std::size_t>(height_percentage * static_cast<double>(target_height))
            );
        }
    }
}


find_local_extrema template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace SIFT_impl {
        //  find_local_extrema template function implementation
        template<typename ElementT>
        constexpr static auto find_local_extrema(
            Image<ElementT> input1,
            Image<ElementT> input2,
            Image<ElementT> input3,
            std::size_t octave_index,
            std::size_t scale_index,
            ElementT contrast_check_threshold = 8,
            ElementT edge_response_threshold = 12.1)
        {
            if (input1.getDimensionality() != 2)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
            }
            if (input2.getDimensionality() != 2)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
            }
            if (input3.getDimensionality() != 2)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
            }
            if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
            }
            if (input2.getSize() != input3.getSize())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
            }
            const int block_size = 3;
            std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t, ElementT, ElementT>> output;
            auto width = input1.getWidth() - 1;
            auto height = input1.getHeight() - 1;
            #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
            for (std::size_t y = 1; y < height; ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 1; x < width; ++x)
                {
                    auto subimage1 = subimage(input1, block_size, block_size, x, y);
                    auto subimage2 = subimage(input2, block_size, block_size, x, y);
                    auto subimage3 = subimage(input3, block_size, block_size, x, y);
                    if (is_it_extremum(subimage1, subimage2, subimage3, contrast_check_threshold) && keypoint_filtering(subimage2, contrast_check_threshold, edge_response_threshold))
                    {
                        auto new_location = keypoint_refinement(subimage2, std::make_tuple(x, y));
                        output.emplace_back(
                            std::make_tuple(
                                octave_index,
                                scale_index,
                                std::get<0>(new_location),
                                std::get<1>(new_location)));
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}


generate_octave template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace SIFT_impl {
        //  generate_octave template function implementation
        template<typename ElementT, typename SigmaT = double>
        requires(std::floating_point<SigmaT> || std::integral<SigmaT>)
        constexpr static auto generate_octave(
            const Image<ElementT>& input,
            std::size_t number_of_scale_levels = 5,
            SigmaT initial_sigma = 1.6,
            double k = 1.4142135623730950488016887242097)
        {
            std::vector<Image<ElementT>> difference_of_gaussian_images;
            difference_of_gaussian_images.resize(number_of_scale_levels - 1);
            #pragma omp parallel for
            for (int index = 0; index < number_of_scale_levels - 1; ++index)
            {
                difference_of_gaussian_images[index] = (difference_of_gaussian(input, initial_sigma * std::pow(k, index), initial_sigma * std::pow(k, index + 1)));
            }
            return difference_of_gaussian_images;
        }
    }
}


get_potential_keypoint template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace SIFT_impl {
        //  get_potential_keypoint template function implementation
        template<typename ElementT = double, typename SigmaT = double>
        requires(   (std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT>) &&
                    (std::floating_point<SigmaT> || std::integral<SigmaT>))
        constexpr static auto get_potential_keypoint(
            const Image<ElementT>& input,
            std::size_t octaves_count = 4,
            std::size_t number_of_scale_levels = 5,
            SigmaT initial_sigma = 1.6,
            double k = 1.4142135623730950488016887242097,
            ElementT contrast_check_threshold = 8,
            ElementT edge_response_threshold = 12.1)
        {
            if (input.getDimensionality() != 2)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
            }
            //  Generate octaves
            std::vector<std::vector<Image<ElementT>>> octaves;
            octaves.reserve(octaves_count);
            Image<ElementT> base_image = input;
            for (std::size_t octave_index = 0; octave_index < octaves_count; ++octave_index)
            {
                octaves.emplace_back(generate_octave(base_image, number_of_scale_levels, initial_sigma, k));
                base_image = copyResizeBicubic(
                    base_image,
                    static_cast<std::size_t>(static_cast<double>(base_image.getWidth()) / 2.0),
                    static_cast<std::size_t>(static_cast<double>(base_image.getHeight()) / 2.0));
            }

            //  Find potential KeyPoints
            /*  KeyPoint structure: octave_index, scale_index + 1, location_x, location_y
            */
            std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t, ElementT, ElementT>> keypoints;
            #pragma omp parallel for
            for (int octave_index = 0; octave_index < octaves_count; ++octave_index)
            {
                auto each_octave = octaves[octave_index];
                #pragma omp parallel for
                for (int scale_index = 0; scale_index < each_octave.size() - 2; ++scale_index)
                {
                    /* if `append_range` function is supported
                    keypoints.append_range(
                        find_local_extrema(
                            each_octave[scale_index],
                            each_octave[scale_index + 1],
                            each_octave[scale_index + 2],
                            octave_index,
                            scale_index,
                            contrast_check_threshold,
                            edge_response_threshold)
                    );
                    */

                    for (auto&& element : find_local_extrema(
                        each_octave[scale_index],
                        each_octave[scale_index + 1],
                        each_octave[scale_index + 2],
                        octave_index,
                        scale_index,
                        contrast_check_threshold,
                        edge_response_threshold))
                    {
                        keypoints.emplace_back(element);
                    }
                }
            }

            //  mapping keypoints in different scale to the original image
            std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>> mapped_keypoints;
            for (auto&& each_keypoint : keypoints)
            {
                auto input_width = octaves[std::get<0>(each_keypoint)][0].getWidth();
                auto input_height = octaves[std::get<0>(each_keypoint)][0].getHeight();
                mapped_keypoints.emplace_back(
                    mapping_point(
                        std::make_tuple(std::get<2>(each_keypoint), std::get<3>(each_keypoint)),
                        input_width,
                        input_height,
                        input.getWidth(),
                        input.getHeight()
                    ));
            }

            return mapped_keypoints;
        }
    }
}


copyResizeBicubic template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  copyResizeBicubic template function implementation
    template<class FloatingType = float, arithmetic ElementT>
    constexpr static Image<ElementT> copyResizeBicubic(Image<ElementT>& image, std::size_t width, std::size_t height)
    {
        Image<ElementT> output(width, height);
        //  get used to the C++ way of casting
        auto ratiox = static_cast<FloatingType>(image.getWidth()) / static_cast<FloatingType>(width);
        auto ratioy = static_cast<FloatingType>(image.getHeight()) / static_cast<FloatingType>(height);
        #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                FloatingType xMappingToOrigin = static_cast<FloatingType>(x) * ratiox;
                FloatingType yMappingToOrigin = static_cast<FloatingType>(y) * ratioy;
                FloatingType xMappingToOriginFloor = std::floor(xMappingToOrigin);
                FloatingType yMappingToOriginFloor = std::floor(yMappingToOrigin);
                FloatingType xMappingToOriginFrac = xMappingToOrigin - xMappingToOriginFloor;
                FloatingType yMappingToOriginFrac = yMappingToOrigin - yMappingToOriginFloor;

                ElementT ndata[4 * 4];
                for (int ndatay = -1; ndatay <= 2; ++ndatay)
                {
                    for (int ndatax = -1; ndatax <= 2; ++ndatax)
                    {
                        ndata[(ndatay + 1) * 4 + (ndatax + 1)] = image.at(
                            std::clamp(xMappingToOriginFloor + ndatax, static_cast<FloatingType>(0), static_cast<FloatingType>(image.getWidth()) - static_cast<FloatingType>(1)), 
                            std::clamp(yMappingToOriginFloor + ndatay, static_cast<FloatingType>(0), static_cast<FloatingType>(image.getHeight()) - static_cast<FloatingType>(1)));
                    }

                }
                output.at(x, y) = bicubicPolate(ndata, xMappingToOriginFrac, yMappingToOriginFrac);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    //  copyResizeBicubic template function implementation for color image
    template<class FloatingType = double, class ElementT>
    requires (std::same_as<ElementT, RGB> || (std::same_as<ElementT, RGB_DOUBLE>))
    Image<ElementT> copyResizeBicubic(Image<ElementT>& image, std::size_t width, std::size_t height)
    {
        return TinyDIP::apply_each(image, [&](auto&& each_plane)
        {
            return TinyDIP::copyResizeBicubic<FloatingType>(each_plane, width, height);
        });
    }
}


bicubicPolate template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    template<class InputT = float, class ElementT>
    constexpr static auto bicubicPolate(const ElementT* const ndata, const InputT fracx, const InputT fracy)
    {
        auto x1 = cubicPolate( ndata[0], ndata[1], ndata[2], ndata[3], fracx );
        auto x2 = cubicPolate( ndata[4], ndata[5], ndata[6], ndata[7], fracx );
        auto x3 = cubicPolate( ndata[8], ndata[9], ndata[10], ndata[11], fracx );
        auto x4 = cubicPolate( ndata[12], ndata[13], ndata[14], ndata[15], fracx );

        return std::clamp(
                    static_cast<InputT>(cubicPolate(x1, x2, x3, x4, fracy)),
                    static_cast<InputT>(std::numeric_limits<ElementT>::min()),
                    static_cast<InputT>(std::numeric_limits<ElementT>::max()));
    }
}


cubicPolate template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    template<class InputT1, class InputT2>
    constexpr static auto cubicPolate(const InputT1 v0, const InputT1 v1, const InputT1 v2, const InputT1 v3, const InputT2 frac)
    {
        auto A = (v3-v2)-(v0-v1);
        auto B = (v0-v1)-A;
        auto C = v2-v0;
        auto D = v1;
        return D + frac * (C + frac * (B + frac * A));
    }
}


draw_point template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  draw_point template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr static auto draw_point(
        const Image<ElementT>& input,
        std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t> point,
        ElementT draw_value = ElementT{},
        std::size_t radius = 3
        )
    {
        auto point_x = std::get<0>(point);
        auto point_y = std::get<1>(point);
        auto output = input;
        auto height = input.getHeight();
        auto width = input.getWidth();
        #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
        for (std::size_t y = point_y - radius; y <= point_y + radius; ++y)
        {
            for (std::size_t x = point_x - radius; x <= point_x + radius; ++x)
            {
                if (x >= width || y >= height)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if(std::pow(static_cast<double>(x) - static_cast<double>(point_x), 2.0) +
                   std::pow(static_cast<double>(y) - static_cast<double>(point_y), 2.0) < std::pow(radius, 2))
                {
                    output.at_without_boundary_check(x, y) = draw_value;
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}


draw_points template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  draw_points template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr static auto draw_points(
        const Image<ElementT>& input,
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>> points,
        ElementT draw_value = ElementT{},
        std::size_t radius = 3
    )
    {
        auto output = input;
        for (auto&& each_point : points)
        {
            output = draw_point(output, each_point, draw_value, radius);
        }
        return output;
    }
}


apply_each template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(Image<RGB> input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getRplane(input), args...); });
        auto Gplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getGplane(input), args...); });
        auto Bplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getBplane(input), args...); });
        return constructRGB(Rplane.get(), Gplane.get(), Bplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(Image<RGB_DOUBLE> input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getRplane(input), args...); });
        auto Gplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getGplane(input), args...); });
        auto Bplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getBplane(input), args...); });
        return constructRGBDOUBLE(Rplane.get(), Gplane.get(), Bplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(Image<HSV> input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Hplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getHplane(input), args...); });
        auto Splane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getSplane(input), args...); });
        auto Vplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return operation(getVplane(input), args...); });
        return constructHSV(Hplane.get(), Splane.get(), Vplane.get());
    }
}


getRplane function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  getRplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getRplane(Image<RGB> input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 0);
    }

    //  getRplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getRplane(Image<RGB_DOUBLE> input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 0);
    }
}


getGplane function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  getGplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getGplane(Image<RGB> input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 1);
    }

    //  getGplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getGplane(Image<RGB_DOUBLE> input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 1);
    }
}


getBplane function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  getBplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getBplane(Image<RGB> input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 2);
    }

    //  getBplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getBplane(Image<RGB_DOUBLE> input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 2);
    }
}


constructRGB function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  constructRGB template function implementation
    template<typename OutputT = RGB>
    constexpr static auto constructRGB(Image<GrayScale> r, Image<GrayScale> g, Image<GrayScale> b)
    {
        check_size_same(r, g);
        check_size_same(g, b);
        auto image_data_r = r.getImageData();
        auto image_data_g = g.getImageData();
        auto image_data_b = b.getImageData();
        std::vector<OutputT> new_data;
        new_data.resize(r.count());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < r.count(); ++index)
        {
            OutputT rgb {   image_data_r[index],
                        image_data_g[index],
                        image_data_b[index]};
            new_data[index] = rgb;
        }
        Image<OutputT> output(new_data, r.getSize());
        return output;
    }
}



The usage of get_potential_keypoint template function:
int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::string file_path = "InputImages/1";
    auto bmp1 = TinyDIP::bmp_read(file_path.c_str(), false);
    bmp1 = copyResizeBicubic(bmp1, bmp1.getWidth() * 2, bmp1.getHeight() * 2);
    auto SIFT_keypoints = TinyDIP::SIFT_impl::get_potential_keypoint(
        TinyDIP::getVplane(TinyDIP::rgb2hsv(bmp1)));
    std::cout << "SIFT_keypoints count = " << SIFT_keypoints.size() << "\n";
    RGB rgb{ 255, 255, 255 };
    bmp1 = TinyDIP::draw_points(bmp1, SIFT_keypoints, rgb);
    TinyDIP::bmp_write("test20240809", bmp1);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The output of the test code above:
Width of the input image: 512
Height of the input image: 512
Size of the input image(Byte): 786432
SIFT_keypoints count = 430
Computation finished at Fri Aug  9 15:04:24 2024
elapsed time: 60.1763

TinyDIP on GitHub
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
difference_of_gaussian Template Function Implementation for Image in C++,
conv2 Template Function Implementation for Image in C++ and
imgaussfilt Template Function Implementation for Image in C++

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to perform SIFT (Scale Invariant Feature Transform) keypoint detection in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
Please review the implementation of get_potential_keypoint template function and the related functions.


